# Need to generate key for azure to login VM using cisco process orchestrator

Tags: git, powershell, azure

I generated key in local for azure using git bash with the below command and can able to login  in VM with the key that is generated

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout reee.key -out dfff.pem

But in CPO , cannot run the git command directly , so entered into git bash using powershell with the below command

& 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Git\bin\sh.exe' --login (enter into git bash)

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout reee.key -out dfff.pem

but the process is getting time out .

Please help me in resolving this issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CPO powershell give the below command :

cd C:\Users\username

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\username\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout jj.key -out aa.pem -batch"

Key will get generated and we can use those key for creating a VM in Azure

Comamnd to create a VM in azure:
azure vm create azurekeytest   --ssh 22 --no-ssh-password --ssh-cert  C:\Users\username\aa.pem --location "East US" --vm-size extrasmall